# $X=\{A_i\subset\Omega$ , such that either $A_i$ is finite or $A_i^c$ is finite$\}$. Is $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ finite or its complement is finite?

Tags: measure-theory

It is given that $\Omega$ is an uncountable set. $X=\{A_i\subset\Omega$ , such that either $A_i$ is finite or $A_i^c$ is finite$\}$. I have to show that whether $X$ is $\sigma-$algebra or not.

I am able to show that $\phi\in X$  and $\forall A_i\in X, A^c\in X$

I am not able to find, how do I show that if $\cup_{i=1}^{\infty}A_i$ is finite or not  or its complement.

Comment: What happens if $\Omega =\mathbb{R}$ and $A_i=\{i\}$?

Comment: @GrafZahl I think the union in this case will not be finite but countable infinite. Is it correct?

Comment: yes, the union would be $\mathbb{N}$ and neither this, nor the complement are finite.

Comment: okay. So you mean I can prove this by taking an example.

Comment: Yes, this would be a suitable counterexample, I think.

Comment: Notice that one can still show that $X$ is an algebra, i.e. finite unions are contained in $X$.

Comment: @Graf Zahl it seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score 1):

Proof that not all countable unions are contained in $X$:

Let $\Omega$ be uncountable, $\omega_i\in \Omega$ with $\omega_i\neq \omega_j$ for $i,j\in \mathbb{N}, i\neq j$. Then $\bigcup_{I\in\mathbb{N}}\{\omega_i\}$ is infinite and so is its complement, because otherwise $\Omega$ would be countable.

Proof that finite unions are contained in $X$:

It suffices to show that the union of two sets $A,B\in X$ is again in $X$. So assume $(A\cup B)^c=A^c\cap B^c$ is infinite. Since this is a subset of $A^c$ and $B^c$ they also must be infinite. Since $A,B\in X$, both must be finite, hence also $A\cup B$ must be finite.